# inputing/outputting text in the console while running a class that extends J Frame

Tags: java, swing, oop, jframe, jpanel

So I have mulitple classes. lets assume
Class Animation extends JFrame

- Static class Canvas extends JPanel

Class Sprite

Class main

Class Game - initializes objects from Class Ship

Class Ship

Now this is the overall structure of the main code

```
public class main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Game g = new Game();
g.start();
//rest of the code is from class Animation Canvas and Class Sprite
System.exit(0);
```

now the problem is if class Game and Ship are running first then the jframe and jpanel doesn't open from class Animation and Canvas. And if I put Class Game after running class Animation,Canvas,Sprite. Class Game would not execute. I do not know what im doing wrong.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  And fer chrisssake, give the classes meaningful names.

Comment: ok let me change the class names

Comment: *"let me change the class names"*  Nobody's stopping you, but post an MCVE (with sensibly indented code) while you're at it.

Comment: does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into threading issues by trying to combine an event-driven GUI with a linear console program. The best solution is not to do this, to not accept user input from the command line but rather get all input from the GUI itself in an event-driven way. If you absolutely need to get input from the command line, you'd best justify why this is so (because I'm betting you'd be wrong), and you'd have to do this in a thread that is background to the GUI.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense I was thinking about that, unfortunately I have to get input from the command line, thats what the professor wants   . So what exactly should I write in my code for this to work?

Comment: @Nabmeister: I have no idea since you've posted just the barest outline of your program, one that doesn't really explain anything, and have not yet posted your [minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as has been requested of you in comments to your question. I can help you with code, but only if you first help me out.